# How to update build.gradle dependencies in Capacitor

Tags: android, angular, gradle, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I basically need to implement the following action:

> In your project, open your_app | Gradle Scripts | build.gradle (Module: app) and add the following compile statement to the dependencies{} section to compile the latest version of the SDK:
>
> implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'

The thing is that the app we're working on is an Angular app on which we use Capacitor to convert to an APK, is there a way to configure Capacitor to have these dependencies added into the build.gradle file?

thanks in advance.